# Comment Tag for Variables in VB

Tags: vb.net

When I right click one of my variables in VB and then insert comment, it inserts the same type of comment as it does for functions which is comments with the `<summary>` tag. I was wondering if there is a specific comment tag for variables in VB?

Comment: It's the same for all members (fields, properties, methods, events).  There are certain tags that don't apply to some, e.g. `param`, but the `summary` applies to all because it's the description that gets displayed by Intellisense when you mouse over that member.

Comment: I don't know where the "Insert Comment" comes from. Probably from a Visual Studio extension. You cannot use [XML Comment Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/index) inside methods, since they are intended to document the API. Use normal comments inside methods.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the 'Insert Comment" doesn't come from an extension, it is a part of Visual Studio's Intellisense.

Comment: "right click" isn't Intellisense. I see it now in the sub-menu `Snippet` > `Insert Comment` in the context menu. But even if I call it for a variable, it inserts the comment for the containing method (VS 2017).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that is my question. That is what I was wondering.  I wanted to know if there is a variable specific comment just like there is for parameter which is `<param>`.

Comment: So what is the point of this question? Where would you want to see the comment? With comments on methods they appear in intellisense. Are you talking about intellisense within a method where a commented variable is in scope, being able to see the comment on the variable? Then no it is not possible. You could however create a property instead and comment that, if it's critical to see the comment in intellisense. Hope this helps

Comment: @djv I wanted to comment my variables, especially the global ones and I couldn't find a way to comment them. When I inserted a comment for them, Visual Studio added a `<summary>` comment which I thought was more applicable to methods.

Comment: Since variables are neither visible nor accessible outside of a method, Intellisense help cannot be provided for them outside of the method. If you need this kind of help inside the method, then probably your method is too long! "Global ones" are called "fields" and you can use doc comments for them.

Comment: If you simply want to add a normal comment then type the introducing `'` manually. This is faster than right click + click submenu + click command.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that's what I did for the variables

Comment: The short answer is: No, there is no specific comment tag for variables. Doc comments work for fields but not for variables.